# If I have x32 and x64 python, how can I make a .py file specifically in x32 and not in x64?

Tags: python, pip, compatibility, 32bit-64bit

I first downloaded python x64. Now, I have both python x64 and python x32. How can I create a python file for just the x32, and not the x64?

Edit:
I thought this was a duplicate, but it was not, the other answer does not have a response that works.

Comment: use the x32 version of python to make the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect current python is 32-bit or 64-bit.

```
import platform
print(platform.architecture()[0])
```

You can then write code accordingly ...

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be what they're asking for

Answer (score 1):

Python is an interpreted language, so Python files can always run in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments, with the same behaviour and output (in most cases).

If you want to control which Python instance your code runs with, you should start the program by giving the direct path to the version of Python which you intend to run.